# Hide poi.business markers/labels in Google Static Maps API

Tags: api, label, hide, google-maps-static-api, noscript

I'm building a static Google Map URL to be used within `<noscript><noscript>` tag on a 'Find Us' page as fall-back in case a user has scripting turned off. Code thus far is:

```
<div id="map" class="map">
    <noscript>
        <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=[lat],[long]
            &zoom=17
            &size=600x400
            &scale=1
            &maptype=hybrid
            &visible=[lat],[long]
            &key=[key hidden]">
    </noscript>
</div>
```

However, on the resulting map image, there are markers for other businesses (e.g. orange knife & fork markers for restaurants) and/or points of interest.

I want to suppress the display of these markers, and add a custom marker for my location of interest (&`markers=....` not shown in the code snippet above).

I cannot find anything in the Static Maps API documentation, nor on stackoverflow.

Is there a way to achieve this, or am I stuck with them on a Static Map?

Answer (score 29):

Tack this on your query string:

```
style=feature:poi|visibility:off
```

You can find other stylings [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/styling).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  How did I not find [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/styling)?  Doh!